# Handle return from the minimized state

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle

in my application I want to ask the user for a password every time when he gets application from minimized state.

ie the user is working, then turned the app off and then to get into it again, he has to enter a password.

How can I handle return from the minimized state?

onResume() doesn't help.

handles pressing the home button is also not suitable because the user can go to another application in different ways.
can anyone tell me what to do?

Comment: I think you should be able to accomplish this with intent filters.

Comment: i've been tried to do such way, but i had no result